# Изменить индекс массива значением другого массива

Tags: массивы, php

Как изменить индекс массива значением другого массива? Имеем 2 массива:

Первый массив:

```
$array1('hello', 'world');
```

Второй массив:

```
$array2 = array('one', 'two');
```

В результате нужно получить следующий массив:

```
$array3 = array("one" => "hello", "two" => "world");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[array_combine](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-combine.php)

> Создает array, используя значения массива keys в качестве ключей и значения масссива values в качестве соответствующих значений.

Answer (score 2):

[array_combine](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-combine.php) - Создает новый массив, используя один массив в качестве ключей, а другой в качестве соответствующих значений!

Answer (score -1):

```
$array1 = array('hello', 'world');
$array2 = array('one', 'two');
$array3 = array();
//echo count($array1);
for($i=0;$i<count($array1);$i++){
    $array3[$array2[$i]] = $array1[$i];
}
foreach($array3 as $k => $v){ echo $k.':'.$v.'<br />'; }
```

А за что мне минусы влепили?